# Change current record ID in URL

Tags: apex, visualforce, url, parameters

I have a toggle button between 2 different views (detail and list) of an object (ie all calls for a sales rep).

In the list view the sales rep or the date can be changed to retrieve for another rep or for another date. When I click the toggle button however to display the detail view, it displays the original record selected, not the new one, as the ID parameter in the URL doesn't change when I select a new record.

How do I get it to change the ID in the URL to the latest one? In my commandbutton I put in the new ID as below, yet when it loads the detail view through the controller it loads the old one.

```
  <apex:commandButton id="CCActivitiesView" action="{!view}" title="Call Cycle Activities View" value="Call Cycle Activities Detail View" 
        onclick="location.href=('/apex/CallCycleView?id={!CallCycle.Id}')" />
```

This is my Controller code:

```
public CallCycleController(ApexPages.StandardController std) {

stdCtrl=std;        
CallCycle = (CallCycle__c)std.getRecord();
date ccDate = CallCycle.Date__c;

if(CallCycle != null && CallCycle.Id != null){
    CallCycle = [Select Id, OwnerId, Name, Date__c, CycleStart__c, CycleEnd__c, SalesPerson__c, SalesPerson__r.Name
                 From CallCycle__c Where Id = :CallCycle.Id];
    LoadModel();
}
```

}

Comment: What is your code for the inputfield for CallCycle?

Comment: There is no input field - it selects the CallCycle based on the Salesrep and the date. I then get the ID of the record from the query results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the value of {!CallCycle.Id} is loaded and set during loading the page. Not matter how you change the value later on at controller side, at client side, the url will not update, unless you rerender that part.

To resolve this, the simplest way is to move the redirection code into server side. And you should be able to use the updated CallCyle.Id value then.

Comment: Sorry Lance I'm not sure of how to do what you suggest - could you show me with code what you mean please?

Comment: Ok, I managed to figure it out and got it working. I created a PageReference in the Controller and changed the button to call that instead.                 <apex:commandButton id="CCActivitiesView" action="{!GetDetailActivities}" title="Call Cycle Activities View" value="Activities Detail View" />